# Is it possible to generate irrationals in a set full of irrational numbers?

Tags: probability-theory, intuition

I was thinking about the process of selecting a real uniformly at random in the interval $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$. I know that the probability of picking a rational number is 0 and the probability of picking an irrational number is 1. However, when I ask a computer to generate something like this, using for example in Python, the`random.uniform(0, 1)` I will always get a rational number even though the probability of picking a rational is $0$. I was wondering if on a computer we could call a function that really generates uniformly a real between 0 and 1 and so that in particular would also generate irrational numbers. Maybe this question was already asked but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: How do you know that random.uniform is producing a rational number?

Comment: If it generates an irrational number, do expect it to output all the decimals?  How will that work?

Comment: @Gregory: all real numbers in programming languages like python are rational.

Comment: And only a tiny fraction of the rationals.

Comment: There is a well-defined notion of a [computable real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) which embraces all the familiar irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$, $e$ and $\pi$. Unfortunately, using computable reals doesn't get you out of your dilemma since almost all real numbers are not computable.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, of course all real numbers in programming languages are rational... and Gregory's question may have been a sort of [leading question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_question) wherein if the OP were able to answer that, by answering and recognizing that computers are limited in their capabilities we have that programming languages and computers are just picking a *float* at random, clearly not only is having the computer picking a random number not picking irrationals... it is picking only from a finite collection of possibilities, the OP would have the answer themselves.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I said "real numbers in programming languages like python are rational". There is not "of course" in there: a programming language whose real numbers range over computable reals that can be represented within the resources of the computer is perfectly feasible. Also feasible, moving away from the notion of computable reals, is a random number generator which repeatedly uses an external source of entropy to give an infinite set of outputs (unless you apply your kind of argument to limitations on time as well as space).

Comment: It is quite easy to have a computer generate, say, "random" numbers that are rational multiples of $\pi$.  Of course, such a number will not be represented in the computer by its decimal expansion, but rather by an expression such as 0.34656*Pi.

Answer (score 7):

Any actual, physical computer has finite memory, that can only be in some finite number of possible states, and thus can only represent a finite number of numbers. So any random distribution used by a computer to generate (pseudo-)random numbers must be a discrete distribution. Different (non-standard) ways to represent numbers will definitely make it possible to get irrational numbers. But no matter how you choose to represent your numbers, you will not be able to overcome the fundamental finiteness restriction at the heart of this.